# Producer/Consumer - Queue.get by list

Tags: python, django-views, queue, buffer, producer-consumer

I am trying to get data from DB in order to input to machine Learning model. But my Producer only put data to queue one by one row in DB and Consumer also only get one by one. My machine learning Model needs 2000 rows to process.

I want Producer and Consumer puts and gets by a mount of rows per time, not only one by one

here is my code in python

```
def read_data():
    
    torque_data_queryset = Torque.get_torque_data()
    return list(torque_data_queryset)


def producer(queue):
    print('Producer: Running')
    data = read_data()
    for item in data:
       
        time.sleep(1)
        
        queue.put(item)
        print(f'> Producer added {item}')
    
    queue.put(None)
    print('Producer: Done')

# consumer task
def consumer(queue):
    print('Consumer: Running')
    while True:
        
        item = queue.get()
        print(item)
        
        if item is None:
            break
        
        time.sleep(1)
        
        print(f'> Consumer got {item}')
    print('Consumer: Done')

def thread_function():
    
    queue = Queue()
    
    consumer_thread = Thread(target=consumer, args=(queue,))
    consumer_thread.start()
    
    producer_thread = Thread(target=producer, args=(queue,))
    producer_thread.start()
    
    producer_thread.join()
    consumer_thread.join()
    
def thread_result(request):
    
    thread_function()
    return render(request, 'async_processing_result.html', {'message': 'Threads completed successfully!'})
```

Comment: What is your concern? Is it performance? If so, take out the *sleep()* calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can *put()* a list of objects onto queue.Queue. The consumer will *get()* the entire list at once.

For example:

```
import threading
import queue


def consumer(q: queue.Queue):
    while (value := q.get()) is not None:
        print(*value, sep="\n")


def producer(q: queue.Queue):
    # create a list of dictionaries
    data = [{"int": i, "chr": chr(i + ord("a"))} for i in range(10)]
    q.put(data)
    q.put(None)


def main():
    q = queue.Queue()
    threads = []
    for func in producer, consumer:
        (t := threading.Thread(target=func, args=(q,))).start()
        threads.append(t)
    for t in threads:
        t.join()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Output:**

```
{'int': 0, 'chr': 'a'}
{'int': 1, 'chr': 'b'}
{'int': 2, 'chr': 'c'}
{'int': 3, 'chr': 'd'}
{'int': 4, 'chr': 'e'}
{'int': 5, 'chr': 'f'}
{'int': 6, 'chr': 'g'}
{'int': 7, 'chr': 'h'}
{'int': 8, 'chr': 'i'}
{'int': 9, 'chr': 'j'}
```